# Finding Foreign Keys From Unknown Database SQL and Java

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I have a java program that queries through any type of database with any amount of tables. The user can put in a string and it will return the table and rows containing that string. The problem is that some of these tables have foreign keys. How could I recursively go through all of tables finding foreign keys and rows without any knowledge before hand about the Database?

Plateform: Windows 7(64)
Database Type : Postgres

Code:

```
 public static void connectPostGres(String type, String server, String database, String port, String username, String password) {
        System.out.println("-------- PostgreSQL JDBC Connection Testing ------------");
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Where is your PostgreSQL JDBC Driver? Include in your library path!");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("PostgreSQL JDBC Driver Registered!");
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://" + server + ":" + port + "/" + database, username, password);
            //connection = DriverManager.getConnection("*********);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("doh!");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        if (connection != null) {
            System.out.println("Searching...");
            LinkedList allTables = new LinkedList();
            try {
                Statement st = connection.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from pg_tables");//get all the tables
                while (rs.next()) {
                    String myString = rs.getString("tablename");
                    if (myString.trim().charAt(0) == 'p' && myString.trim().charAt(1) == 'g') {
                        //this is just some crappy tables we dont want to query through
                    } else if (myString.trim().charAt(0) == 's' && myString.trim().charAt(1) == 'q' && myString.trim().charAt(2) == 'l') {
                        //this is just some crappy tables we dont want to query through
                    } else {
                        allTables.add(myString);//add all tables to a linkedlist
                    }
                }

                rs.close();
                String masterQuery = "";
                for (int i = 0; i  columnList = new LinkedList();
                    for (int j = 1; j  0) {
                        for (int j = 0; j
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read this informative [article](http://www.alberton.info/postgresql_meta_info.html) about retrieving postgres meta data.

Typically you have to dig through INFORMATION SCHEMA or use system catalog.

**EDIT**
Also, put as much of your logic into SQL to avoid retrieving and processing the data you don't need at all.

Here's a copy/paste from mentioned article, that lists all constraints (you'll find both approaches here)

```
SELECT c.conname AS constraint_name,
          CASE c.contype
            WHEN 'c' THEN 'CHECK'
            WHEN 'f' THEN 'FOREIGN KEY'
            WHEN 'p' THEN 'PRIMARY KEY'
            WHEN 'u' THEN 'UNIQUE'
          END AS "constraint_type",
          CASE WHEN c.condeferrable = 'f' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS is_deferrable,
          CASE WHEN c.condeferred = 'f' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS is_deferred,
          t.relname AS table_name,
          array_to_string(c.conkey, ' ') AS constraint_key,
          CASE confupdtype
            WHEN 'a' THEN 'NO ACTION'
            WHEN 'r' THEN 'RESTRICT'
            WHEN 'c' THEN 'CASCADE'
            WHEN 'n' THEN 'SET NULL'
            WHEN 'd' THEN 'SET DEFAULT'
          END AS on_update,
          CASE confdeltype
            WHEN 'a' THEN 'NO ACTION'
            WHEN 'r' THEN 'RESTRICT'
            WHEN 'c' THEN 'CASCADE'
            WHEN 'n' THEN 'SET NULL'
            WHEN 'd' THEN 'SET DEFAULT'
          END AS on_delete,
          CASE confmatchtype
            WHEN 'u' THEN 'UNSPECIFIED'
            WHEN 'f' THEN 'FULL'
            WHEN 'p' THEN 'PARTIAL'
          END AS match_type,
          t2.relname AS references_table,
          array_to_string(c.confkey, ' ') AS fk_constraint_key
     FROM pg_constraint c
LEFT JOIN pg_class t  ON c.conrelid  = t.oid
LEFT JOIN pg_class t2 ON c.confrelid = t2.oid
    WHERE t.relname = 'testconstraints2'
     AND c.conname = 'testconstraints_id_fk';

-- with INFORMATION_SCHEMA:

   SELECT tc.constraint_name,
          tc.constraint_type,
          tc.table_name,
          kcu.column_name,
      tc.is_deferrable,
          tc.initially_deferred,
          rc.match_option AS match_type,
          rc.update_rule AS on_update,
          rc.delete_rule AS on_delete,
          ccu.table_name AS references_table,
          ccu.column_name AS references_field
     FROM information_schema.table_constraints tc
LEFT JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage kcu
       ON tc.constraint_catalog = kcu.constraint_catalog
      AND tc.constraint_schema = kcu.constraint_schema
      AND tc.constraint_name = kcu.constraint_name
LEFT JOIN information_schema.referential_constraints rc
       ON tc.constraint_catalog = rc.constraint_catalog
      AND tc.constraint_schema = rc.constraint_schema
      AND tc.constraint_name = rc.constraint_name
LEFT JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage ccu
       ON rc.unique_constraint_catalog = ccu.constraint_catalog
      AND rc.unique_constraint_schema = ccu.constraint_schema
      AND rc.unique_constraint_name = ccu.constraint_name
    WHERE tc.table_name = 'testconstraints2'
      AND tc.constraint_name = 'testconstraints_id_fk';
```

Comment: Additional link: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/catalog-pg-constraint.html

Comment: Wow that was fast. Thank you. I will give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

You can query the DatabaseMetaData for this type of information:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        Class.forName(DRIVER);
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

        DatabaseMetaData metadata = connection.getMetaData();
        ResultSet resultSet = metadata
            .getExportedKeys(null, null, TABLE);
        while (resultSet.next()) {
        String pkTableName = resultSet.getString("PKTABLE_NAME");
        String pkColName = resultSet.getString("PKCOLUMN_NAME");
        String fkTableName = resultSet.getString("FKTABLE_NAME");
        String fkColName = resultSet.getString("FKCOLUMN_NAME");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        connection.close();
    }
    }
```

See [DatabaseMetaData](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getExportedKeys%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)